# Gradle not able to build, find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle, program-entry-point

I'm going through the lesson of creating my first program on Java and using a gradle to compile and build.

Here is the code of the program

```
class HelloGradle{
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}}
```

I put my file into src->main->java->HelloGradle.java

Then I created `build.gradle` file with such parameters inside `apply plugin: 'java'`

When I try to build using `gradle build` it's says that BUILD success-full and create build folder
So I add such lines to `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "HelloGradle"
```

Then I try to run it from a root folder with such command `gradle run`. But build is got failed. Here is the log of an error

```
Task :run FAILED
Task ':run' is not up-to-date because:
Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''.
     Working directory: /Users/dmytro/Desktop/java/sandbox
     Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
     -cp /Users/dmytro/Desktop/java/sandbox/build/classes/java/main:/Users/dmytro/Desktop/java/sandbox/build/resources/main
     HelloGradle
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloGradle
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloGradle``
```

So it seems like gradle not able to find class file even though that I specified it in configuration file. What is my next step to find a solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does your code have a package name?  Gradle probably is looking for the full name of the class.  `mainClassName = "org.gradle.sample.HelloGradle"`

Comment: I tried to change a configuration file as you suggested with no luck so far. Same error. Could not locate the main method.
My code doesn't have a package name.

Comment: Try `public class HelloGradle` and also use an IDE

Comment: Where is your java file located?  What is its package?

Comment: exactly main class should be public

Comment: In general Java classes should always have a package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17798226/179850

Answer (score 0):

Wow I just started a course to learn Java and typed exactly as it was on video but there was no explanation what is `public` and that is why `gradle` was not able to find it.

But as soon as I add in a code. It was successfully build and run ok in terminal. Thanks everyone . Lesson learned

Comment: What does "add in a code" mean?  Can you be more explicit so that others can learn from you?  Maybe show the config lines that were missing?